# Linetype of contours in gnuplot to all solid

Tags: gnuplot

Consider the following sample script (from the demo) in gnuplot 4.6.2.

```
set terminal epslatex
set output "test.tex"

set view 60, 30, 0.85, 1.1
set samples 20, 20
set isosamples 21, 21
set contour base
set cntrparam levels incremental -100,10,110
set title "3D gnuplot demo - contour plot (every 10, starting at -100)" 
set xlabel "X axis" 
set ylabel "Y axis" 
set zlabel "Z axis" 
set zlabel  offset character 1, 0, 0 font "" textcolor lt -1 norotate
splot x*y
```

I am using the `epslatex` terminal, and my problem is that the contours drawn get all kinds of dashes, even though I just want to have them as solid black curves.

I found that the following solution might work,

```
set style line 1 linetype -1
set style line 2 linetype -1
.
.
set style increment user
```

however, `set style increment user` is deprecated according to the help file, also, I have a multiplot with many lines, and this solution did not really help.

I also tried

```
set termoption solid
```

but without success. I also read solution to write it to `table` and plot. That might work, but as I am using a multiplot, I would rather not do that.

How can I make all contourlines in the `epslatex` terminal solid (and black)?

Comment: Using `set termoption solid` works fine for me with 4.6.5.

Comment: @Christoph I am using 4.6.2 at the moment. Would this an update implemented in between these versions?

Comment: At the moment I can only test on Windows with 4.6.0 and 4.6.5: In both cases `set termoption solid` works fine.

Comment: @Christoph I tested now with 4.6.5 as well (Linux), and on 4.6.5 it also seems to work. Weird that the feature is missing in 4.6.2 then.

Comment: Now I also tested `solid` with 4.6.2 on Linux, but still I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, that is weird :o

Comment: Indeed. Can you upload only the eps somewhere, which you generate with 4.6.2 and `set terminal epslatex solid` and which shows dashed contour lines? My last guess would be, that gnuplot uses the wrong prologue.ps file.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, you just solved my problem. `set termoption solid` does not work, but `set terminal epslatex solid` does!

Comment: Yay :) I'll see later if I can provide a reasonable answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the epslatex terminal which is also present in version 4.6.5. Usually `set termoption solid` works fine. The script

```
set terminal postscript eps
set termoption solid
set output 'solid.eps'
plot x, 2*x
```

correctly plots two solid lines (also works as expected with the `pngcairo`, `wxt`, `svg` terminals etc.)

With the epslatex terminal, however, this is ignored and you must give the `solid` directly when setting the terminal:

```
set terminal epslatex solid
set output 'solid.tex'
plot x, 2*x
```

Comment: Hmm, ok, I keep finding these bugs due to all my special requirements ;)